# How to save a function as input parameter in python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, file-io

I have written a script you could basically reduce to the following:

```
def Readhtml(a,b):
    read some values from an html file
    return a list of values

def ReadSQL(a,b):
    Read some values from an SQL Database
    return a list of values

def mainfunction(Variable):
    result = Variable['Readfunction'](Variable['Parameter1'],Variable['Parameter2']) #Variable['Readfunction'] is the function Readhtml or ReadSQL
    return result
```

where `Variable` is a dictionary with as set of input parameters.

Some of those input parameters are functions to use to read out values or to do operations on them. I have a large number of different variables (about 1000) each of which has a dictionary associated. As long as I define my input dictionary at the beginning of my script everything works fine. But I would like to be able to reuse those dictionaries and thus to save them to a / multiple human readable and writable input file / input files. The problem is I can't figure out how to save / read the dictionary entry `Variable['Readfunction']` in such a way python understands it's not just a string but the function defined in my script I want to use.

Thus I have two questions:

1. I could just write a dirty workaround, saving the Variable['Readfunction'] as string to a file, reread it as string and write a function matching the function name string to the function. Is there a better way?
2. Is the whole architecture none-sense? Should I have built it in a complete other way to avoid that problem? I'm not that great of a programmer, so how should you do such a thing in a proper way? The program is already to complex to rewrite it completely, so this is more about learning for the next time.

Answer (score 2):

That's what `pickling` and object serialization is for.

[Documentation of pickle library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.htm)

Sample Code:-

```
import cPickle as pickle

variable = {'read_function': ReadHtml, 'Parameter1': 'abc'}
dump = pickle.dumps(variable)

# store dump in somewhere

variable = pickle.loads(dump)
```

PS - Your naming conventions are making my eyes hurt. Go through [pep 8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: OP says he wants the files to be human readable.  That isn't true of `pickle` files, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Move the definitions to another script and import that script.  The difficulty with this is in the names.  If you call the script say, "definitions.py" and at the top of your scripts you write

```
import definitions as defn
```

then you'll have to to refer to the variables as `defn.Readhtml` and so forth.  You can use

```
from definitions import *
```

and then you don't have to qualify the names, but "That way madness lies," because you can't tell which names are defined in which module.

So this will do what you want, I think, but may require substantial rewriting, depending on what your scripts are like.